# INSERT INTO get primary key ID from current

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

How can I return the primary key ID value from my most recent query when working in ColdFusion?

For example:

```
<cffunction name="addAction" access="public" returntype="string">
  <cfquery name="newAction" datasource="RC">

    INSERT INTO myTable (name,address,title) VALUE (#fname#,#address#,#usrtitle#);

  </cfquery>

  <cfset actionUpdateID = #result_name.IDENTITYCOL#>

  <cfreturn actionUpdate>
</cffunction>
```

In the example above I am trying to get `actionUpdate` to return the value of the primary key which is a column named `ID`.

Comment: What is the issue with the query above: error, wrong result, ...? What is the data type of your ID column? Without knowing more, `IDENTITYCOL` is for SQL Server only.  Your tags indicate MySQL. For the MySQL property [see the cfquery docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfquery). NB: The feature only works with auto incrementing columns.

Comment: Try adding a result attribute to your cfquery and see if the new id is included.

Comment: MY DB is a SQL server. the ID column is set to int

Comment: Sorry I hadn't seen the mysql tag get applied. It should have been ms-sql.

Comment: (Edit) Take another look at [the docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfquery) :) You need to explicitly add the "result" attribute to your cfquery tag. *RE: the ID column is set to int* As long as it also an `identity` column.

Comment: Thanks Leigh and Dan you are correct I do need the result attribute in there. Someone can put that in an answer and I will check it.

Comment: @DanBracuk responded first. He should post it. (Unless there is a duplicate thread on this somewhere).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working in a reasonably recent version of Microsoft SQL Server, you can use `OUTPUT INSERTED.columnname` with your identity column, like this:

```
<cfquery name="newAction" datasource="RC">
INSERT INTO myTable 
(
  name,
  address,
  title
) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID
VALUES 
(
  #fname#,
  #address#,
  #usrtitle#
)
</cfquery>

<cfset actionUpdateID = newAction.person_id>
```

The example assumes that `ID` is your identity column.

(It also shouldn't need to be said that you should be using `<cfqueryparam ...>`.)

---

Alternatively, assuming you're using a reasonably recent version of ColdFusion, the metadata returned by CFQUERY includes the identity on insert, so long as you define a name for the `result=""` attribute. If you used `myResult` for the name of the result variable, you can use (depending on your flavor of database):

```
myResult.IDENTITYCOL    SQL Server only. The ID of an inserted row.

myResult.ROWID          Oracle only. The ID of an inserted row. This is not
                        the primary key of the row, although you can retrieve
                        rows based on this ID.

myResult.SYB_IDENTITY   Sybase only. The ID of an inserted row.

myResult.SERIAL_COL     Informix only. The ID of an inserted row.

myResult.GENERATED_KEY  MySQL only. The ID of an inserted row. MySQL 3 
                        does not support this feature.

myResult.GENERATEDKEY   Supports all databases. The ID of an inserted row.
```

([ColdFusion documentation](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfquery))

So the example above would look like this:

```
<cfquery name="newAction" datasource="RC" result="queryResults">
INSERT INTO myTable 
(
  name,
  address,
  title
) 
VALUES 
(
  #fname#,
  #address#,
  #usrtitle#
)
</cfquery>

<cfset actionUpdateID = queryResults.IDENTITYCOL>
```

Answer (score 8):

I wrote "[Please stop using SELECT MAX(id)](http://www.iknowkungfoo.com/blog/index.cfm/2008/6/1/please-stop-using-select-max-id)" to cover exactly this issue. Every database has a built-in function that will return the primary key of a newly inserted record on a table.

In SQL Server, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the ID of the last record that was created within the current scope, regardless of the table.

So your function should look more like this:

1. You should be passing in values as arguments of the function (including data type and required values).
2. Your values should be using `CFQUERYPARAM` to protect from SQL Injection attacks.
3. Your function should include `output="false"`.
4. Your function's return type should be `numeric` since you're returning an integer value (the new primary key).

```
<cffunction name="addAction" access="public" output="false" returntype="numeric">
    <cfargument name="fname" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="address" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="usrtitle" type="string" required="true">
    <cfquery name="newAction" datasource="RC">
        INSERT INTO myTable (
            name,
            address,
            title
        ) 
        VALUE (
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.fname#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.address#">,
            <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.usrtitle#">
        );
        // Return the new primary key for this record.
        SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS NEW_ID;
    </cfquery>
    <cfreturn newAction.NEW_ID >
</cffuntion>
```

FWIW, MySQL has the function `LAST_INSERT_ID()` that does the same thing. You will have to update a setting in your data source in CF Admin to [allow MySQL to run multiple statements](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1209-turning-on-multiple-statements-in-coldfusion-8-mysql-4-5-datasource.htm).

Comment: Thank you @Adrian this post was full of great information and tips that I will keep in mind as I move forward with my project. +1

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a result attribute to your cfquery tag.  It should contain the id field you seek.